# Custom cell row height in TableView

Tags: uitableview, ios5

I used Interface Builder to set custom row height to 88.0, but when app runs its height bigger for 10.0 more. 
I tried to use

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

but it produces an error sometimes

```
CALayerInvalidGeometry', reason: 'CALayer bounds contains NaN:...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was with an UIImageView in my cell, that I forget to nil when it doesn't exist.

Also, row height values should be equal both in .m file and storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

`CALayerInvalidGeometry`, reason: '`CALayer bounds contains NaN:...`

This error come when method `heightForRowAtIndexPath` will return the nil value.

Please check the condition and check the array which you pass in it.

Thanks

Comment: I had no conditions... I used return 88.0;
But the question is how to keep custom row height that I filled in in Interface Builder.

Comment: If you want to use custom row height that you filled in Interface Builder. For that simple you enter height in interface builder and remove `- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` above method from code.